# For each loop set value

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Running into a problem. I have two methods with `for each` loops that calculates executives pay either by percentage or base pay. In my Executive class I have my pay method that takes base pay rate and multiplies with bonus. This works if it's percentage but if its base pay and call this method doesn't work. 
Do I have put a if statement in my executive class to see if it's percentage or base pay?

Staff Class

```
/**
 * Assigns the specified flat value weekly bonus to the Executives.
 *
 * @param bonusValue
 *            as a double, i.e., $1,000 = 1000.0
 */

public void setExecutiveBonusFlatRate(double bonusValue) {
    for (StaffMember executiveEmployee : staffList) {
        if (executiveEmployee instanceof Executive) {
            ((Executive) executiveEmployee).setBonus(bonusValue);                         

        }
    }
}



/**
 * Assigns the specified percentage weekly bonus to the Executives.
 * 
 * @param bonus
 *            as a percentage, i.e., 20% = 0.2
 */

public void setExecutiveBonusPercentage(double bonusPercentage) {
    for (StaffMember executiveEmployee : staffList) {
        if (executiveEmployee instanceof Executive) {
            ((Executive) executiveEmployee).setBonus(bonusPercentage);

        }
    }   
}

/**
 * Pays all the staff members.
 */

public void payday() {
   for (StaffMember allEmployee : staffList) {
       allEmployee.toString();
       System.out.println(allEmployee.pay());
       System.out.println(allEmployee.toString());
   }
}
```

From Executive class extended from Employee

```
/**    @overide
 *  return the weekly payrate plus the bonus
 */

public double pay() { 

   double payment = payRate * bonus;
   bonus = 0;
   return payment;
```

Comment: If the `bonus` should be added (instead of a percentage) then `double payment = payRate * bonus;` isn't going to work. I think you'll need to update `pay` in the `setBonus` methods. Or track it with two different `bonus` variables (one for addition, and one for multiplication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to correct two things here:

1. `setExecutiveBonusPercentage` should set the bonus as `base * percentage * 0.01` to be consistent with `bonusValue` set in `setExecutiveBonusFlatRate` as we have no way to know whether `bonus` is a value or percentage.
2. In `pay()` method, we are setting bonus to 0 (`bonus = 0;`) which needs to be removed as it resets the bonus value. Due to this, first call of `pay()` will return correct result whereas subsequent calls will return 0.

Comment: Thank you was missing that.